# How to set the Maximum HTTP Parameter Count on JBoss 5.1.0.GA?

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

I want to set the `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT` property for JBoss 5.1.
I am doing it the following way, but it is not getting affected. Please can anyone help with the right syntax to add this property in the properties-service.xml file?

```
<attribute name="Properties">
    org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT=2
</attribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the setting you are trying to change is for the Tomcat that is embedded within the JBoss server, you have to change the setting in the Tomcat configuration. On JBoss-5.1.0.GA that file is named: `server.xml` and may be found in the Tomcat configuration directory (assuming you are within the root jboss-5.1.0.GA directory): `/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar`. If you are not using the `default` directory to deploy your application(s), replace `default` in the path with: `all`, `minimal`, `standard`, `web`, or whatever you are using.

Within the *server.xml*, you want to find the `Service` configuration entry (on line 9 in the default configuration) and within that entry find the `Connector` configuration entry for the `HTTP` protocol connector (on line 12 in the default configuration). You may set the maximum number of request parameters that will be parsed (which includes `GET` and `POST` requests) using the common connector configuration attribute: `maxParameterCount`.

Starting from the default `HTTP` connector configuration:

```
<Service name="jboss.web">
    <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080"
                address="${jboss.bind.address}"
                connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

You will add the `maxParameterCount` attribute to have:

```
<Service name="jboss.web">
    <Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080"
                address="${jboss.bind.address}"
                connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"
                maxParameterCount="2" />
```

If you want to make this same configuration change for the `HTTPS/SSL/TLS` connector, you will also want to change that protocol connector configuration entry (on line 25 in the default configuration).

Starting from the default `HTTPS/SSL/TLS` connector configuration:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
       port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
       keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/chap8.keystore"
       keystorePass="rmi+ssl" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

You will add the `maxParameterCount` attribute to have:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
       port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
       scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
       keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/chap8.keystore"
       keystorePass="rmi+ssl" sslProtocol = "TLS"
       maxParameterCount="2" />
```

Comment: maxParameterCount is not supported in JBoss EAP 6.3. Any other fix available?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you put it in the proper mbean?  This worked for me, and it looks just about identical to yours.

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.varia.property.SystemPropertiesService" 
     name="jboss:type=Service,name=SystemProperties">

    <attribute name="Properties">
                  org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT=10000
    </attribute>
</mbean>
```

Answer (score 0):

For JBoss 6.3, this worked for me,

Add below entry in standalone.xml file

```
...
</extensions>

<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="5000"/>
</system-properties>

<management>...
```